# c# automapper nested object to flat object list

Tags: .net, automapper

I have the following example structure:

```
public class Client
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Adress> AdressList { get; set; }
}

public class Adress
{
     public Guid Id { get; set; }
     public string street { get; set; }
}
```

I want to automap this structure to something what [normalizr](https://github.com/paularmstrong/normalizr) does for javascript.
I want to have a result that looks like this object

```
public class ViewModelRoot
{
     public ICollection<ViewModelClient> ViewModelClientList { get; set; }
     public ICollection<ViewModelAdress> ViewModelAdressList { get; set; }
}
public class ViewModelClient
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<string> AdressIdList { get; set; }
}

public class ViewModelAdress
{
     public Guid Id { get; set; }
     public string street { get; set; }
}
```

The mapping should extract the AdressList from my Client class to a seperate list on the same level and should replace the References with just its Guids.

I think that could be possible with AutoMapper ... any ideas?
Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: But why is ViewModelClientList a list? Shouldn't it be just a reference?

Comment: It's a redux pattern. In order to deal with NO redundant data in my angular front-end all entities should be managed in a flat format. Nested objects must be extracted. When converting multiple clients both will fit in the same structure.

Answer (score 0):

```
Mapper.Initialize(cfg=>
{
    cfg.CreateMissingTypeMaps = false;
    cfg.CreateMap<Client, ViewModelRoot>()
        .ForMember(d=>d.ViewModelClientList, o=>o.MapFrom(s=>new[]{s}))
        .ForMember(d=>d.ViewModelAdressList, o=>o.MapFrom(s=>s.AdressList));
    cfg.CreateMap<Client, ViewModelClient>()
        .ForMember(d=>d.AdressIdList, o=>o.MapFrom(s=>s.AdressList.Select(a=>a.Id)));
    cfg.CreateMap<Adress, ViewModelAdress>();
});
```