# c# automapper deep nested objects to flat object list

Tags: c#, automapper

I have an additional question regarding this topic: [c# automapper nested object to flat object list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51451127/c-sharp-automapper-nested-object-to-flat-object-list/51454025#51454025)

Just in case I want to extend my example by adding one additional class "Country" which is adressed by my Adress class

```
public class Client
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Adress> AdressList { get; set; }
}

public class Adress
{
     public Guid Id { get; set; }
     public string Street { get; set; }
     public Country Country { get; set; }
}

public class Country
{
     public Guid Id { get; set; }
     public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

and I have to extend my ViewModel like this:

```
public class ViewModelRoot
{
     public ICollection<ViewModelClient> ViewModelClientList { get; set; }
     public ICollection<ViewModelAdress> ViewModelAdressList { get; set; }
     public ICollection<ViewModelCountry> ViewModelCountryList { get; set; }
}
public class ViewModelClient
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<string> AdressIdList { get; set; }
}

public class ViewModelAdress
{
     public Guid Id { get; set; }
     public string Street { get; set; }
     public ICollection<string> CountryId { get; set; }
}

public class ViewModelCountry
{
     public Guid Id { get; set; }
     public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Can I solve this with AutoMapper, too? Keep in mind that it could also happen that I want to map an instance of the class "Adress" instead of "Client" ... I need an overall solution to map an EntityFramework database structure into a structure like "ViewModelRoot".

Comment: Yes to the question you have asked. Are you looking for how as well?

Comment: Yes I am looking to how to implement this ... thx for help. In the end I am trying to have an AutoMapper which transaforms any entity oder entityCollection to my ViewModel and vica versa